# SHA-256 hash of null input?

Tags: hash, sha-256

What is the SHA-256 hash if the input is null, i.e. an empty bitstring? (Not the hash of 0 or "0".)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The result of SHA-256 of an empty string is:

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Accordingly to [this](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/sha_testvectors.html) and [this](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator)

Comment: Verified in Linux with e.g. `sha256sum /dev/null` and `printf | sha256sum`

Comment: Verified in Python with 

`import hashlib; m = hashlib.sha256(); assert m.hexdigest() == 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'
`